# Why so many repositories in ASP.NET Identity's `UserStore`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, nhibernate, asp.net-identity

I am about to undertake a conversion of Identity's `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` project (v 2.0.0.0) to one that uses NHibernate as its persistence machine. My first 'stumbling block' is this set of repositories in the `UserStore` class:

```
private readonly IDbSet<TUserLogin> _logins;
private readonly EntityStore<TRole> _roleStore;
private readonly IDbSet<TUserClaim> _userClaims;
private readonly IDbSet<TUserRole> _userRoles;
private EntityStore<TUser> _userStore;
```

Type parameter `TUser` is constrained to `IdentityUser<TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>`, and this type has its own similar set of collections:

```
public virtual ICollection<TRole> Roles { get; private set; }
public virtual ICollection<TClaim> Claims { get; private set; }
public virtual ICollection<TLogin> Logins { get; private set; }
```

My life would be much easier if I had to manage just one repository, of `TUser`, as each of these users already take care of their own stuff. Is there any important reason I can't just do away with these (in order to do away with any dependencies on Entity Framework, like `DbSet`?

I could contrive my own repository class in place of `DbSet` to conform to this design of `UserStore`, but I would much prefer to just lose them and let each user instance take care of its own claims etc.

Comment: There are many examples of using other database technologies with Identity Framework.  EF is only one of the providers.  For instance, there are 4 existing nHibernate samples already out there, see: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22Identity%22+Tags%3A%22nhibernate%22 - Also, there's source code to some of them.  For instance: https://github.com/MatthewRudolph/Airy

Comment: The first, most prominent project I found for HNibernate forced me to use string keys, in an otherwise totally generic system, a standard I find unacceptable, and I have been tasked with using our existing NHibernate custom DAL for Identity persistence, so I though it best, and most fun, to do mu own. I will, of course, look top the examples you cite for inspiration, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional `DbSet` classes are for persisting data related to a user's claims, roles and logins, while the `ICollection` fields are the navigation properties that allow you to read the data from these tables through your currently selected user.

If you are going for a full conversion of the Identity framework (and god speed to you), you will need these database entities to manage this data.

You could, however, have a single `User` repository that exposes access to their claims, roles and logins to make it a little simpler.

Comment: That single user repository is what I'm wondering why they didn't use in the first place. "and god speed to you" - thank you, this is a very interesting and challenging task as it's my first time working 'inside' Identity and the first time I've ever used NHibernate.

Comment: Do you mean `UserStore`? I think that's more a service class than a repository to expose methods to deal with all of the user information.

Comment: I mean why didn't they have a single user repository within the `UserStore`, as they already have one user repository, `EntityStore<TUser>`, based on a `DbSet`, and in EF, the loading and saving of a user's associated collections can all be handled by the `DbContext` and that `DbSet`, so why must they have 'repositories' for all the user objects collections as well?

Comment: Because `UserClaim`, `UserLogin` and `UserRole` are three different entities with three different concerns that don't really relate to each other. If you're asking why Microsoft didn't just combine them into one, then I'm not the person to ask.

Comment: I was actually asking why MS didn't just have the user repository also persist said those objects that exist as part of the `User` entity anyway. But enough on this, I'll just try doing it 'My Way' for now and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Best of luck ProfK and please report back on how you got on, maybe with an example implementation.  I have an existing system with its own database schema and have basically given up on implemting my own `UserStore` for `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.  Maybe you are a braver person than I!!! :-)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh the closest I got was extending `UserStore` to add in some extra fields. Rewriting the whole thing seems a little like madness.

Comment: @Steve It is madness. I'm only rewriting the end-of-line persistence points, where the store actually makes calls to the `DbContext`, and a few other bits to avoid `DbSet` variables. I'm using the standard, out-of-box, schema.